# react debounce with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I'm trying to implement autocomplete search with debounce,

Below is my attempt using lodash's debounce, 
it seems debouncing is not working.

I'm seeing every character being searched as I type

```
   const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
   const _search = () => {
     console.log('query: ', query)
     // network search request
   }

   const search = _.debounce(_search, 300)

   useEffect(() => {
     search()
   }, [query])

   const handleChangeQuery = useCallback((query) => {
     setQuery(query)
   })
```

** edit **

Following works, yes I mostly got hint from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54666498/433570 
although I think it is very slightly different

Where the linked post chains event setQuery => useEffect => useRef => debounce
Here I'm chaining useCallback => useRef => debounce

Although the core problem (according to the linked post) is you recreate variables inside your component everytime your functional component is called.

`useRef` saves it.

I understood `useCallback` remembers the function but it also loses when the dependant variable changes

It's kinda vague what it means, I thought useCallback gives you memoized function, but if you change the following code from `useRef` to `useCallback` it stops working.. (event though we don't use dependant variable such as `useCallback(() => {}, [var])`

```
const ReviewMetaSelect = (props) => {

  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')


  const search = useRef(_.debounce(query => {

    console.log('query: ', query)

  }, 300))


  // or u can use this
  //const search = useCallback(_.debounce(query => {

    //console.log('query: ', query)

  //}, 300), [])    

   const handleChangeQuery = useCallback((query) => {
     setQuery(query)
     search.current(query) // or search(query) with useCallback
   })

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        value={query}
        onChangeText={handleChangeQuery}
      />
    </View>
  )

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use throttle or debounce with React Hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54666401/how-to-use-throttle-or-debounce-with-react-hook)

Comment: Yes the answer helps a lot.. I added what I found..

Comment: @eugene It's solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60789246/react-why-using-debounce-and-setstate-in-the-same-callback-not-work#60789246

Comment: @keikei I just confirmed it works .. thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can create your custom component Input with a debounce (or use inside another component), with out necesity of a library

For example like some this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const InputDebounce = () => {

    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(text)
            //some function here
        }, 500);

        return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    }, [text])


    return <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />
};

export default InputDebounce;
```

Is very important define the `clearTimeOut`  a return insde of the useEffect,to this working ok.

Comment: This will call the setTimeout function once on every page load.. which might in most cases is not the feature generally you see