# Weird subsequence issue with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

With **class-based** components, I can (for example) do this:

```
doThing = () => {
    this.setState({
        test: 'Zest'
    })

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(this.state.test) // will return 'Zest'
    },1000)

}
```

However, in a functional component with the `useState` hook, the state won't be updated until another event listener is called. My example is most obvious when using `setTimeout` listener, but it shows up in lots of other contexts too.

Once an event listener is called, no state updates are received until another one's called.

Up until now, every time this weird quirk has caused any issues I just change the component back to a class-based one, but I've always wondered what it was about.

Can anyone explain why or offer a means of getting an updated state within a callback/timeout/interval/etc using a functional component and react hooks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60789246/react-why-using-debounce-and-setstate-in-the-same-callback-not-work

Comment: sounds related to [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/1176601) - but please say what you are trying to achieve, list the code that does NOT work for you and what is expected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is. Is it related to `setTimeout`? Because there is a gotcha in react hooks for [setTimeout](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/settimeout-in-react-components-using-hooks) (and [setInterval](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)). `setTimeout` is a closure, therefore, when `setTimeout` is scheduled it uses the value of count at that exact moment in time, which is the initial value.

For [proper use of `setTimeout` in hooks, see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090432/react-hooks-right-way-to-clear-timeouts-and-intervals).

For your very simple example, this is the equivalent code using hooks, and it works:

```js
function App() {
  const [test] = useState("Zest");

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(test);
  }, 1000);
```

Could you demonstrate the AddEventlistener problem you are having?

Also, I'm a bit suspicious of the fact that you need to add event listeners in a react program. You can usually get by just using react `onChange` handlers and suchlike.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why you use `setTimeout`, maybe you know the `this.setState` is an asynchronous function and you used a `setTimeout` to handle an action after the state changed. if it is your goal you should write it like below:

```
doThing = () => {
  this.setState(
    {
      test: 'Zest'
    },
    () => {
      console.log(this.state.test) // **
    }
  );
}
```

Actually, based on [ReactJS docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), the `setState` can get a callback. so if you wanna do something right after changing state use the callback function of `setState`.

### NOW on Function component

For having the above situation on a function component you should write just like below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

const FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState('');
  const doThing = useCallback(() => {
    setTest('Zest');
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(test) // here is exactly like **
  }, [test]);

  return (
    <div // etc...
  );
};
```

The `doThing` function is created just for once at the mounting the `FunctionComponent` because we use `useCallback` and pass `[]` dependency on it. then the callback of `useEffect` frequently runs just after changing state of `test`.