# React setState multiple calls override

Tags: reactjs, performance, use-state

I have some fast updating (external signal) code that I use to setState which triggers a long rerender

sudo code:

```
const FastUpdate = ({signalPoint, otherProp}) => {
   const [state, setState] = useState(null)
   useEffect(() => {
      setState(calcNewState(signalPoint,otherProp))
   },[signalPoint]
   )
   return <VeryTimeConsimingComponent dependency={state}/>
}
```

In this senario that happens to me is that if signalPoint changes 15 times in 1 sec. Then 15 rerenders are triggered. However, by the time the 8th rerender is happening signalPoint has updated 11 times. SO I would like to tell React forget rerender #9,#10 and directly do #11

Is there a way to make this happen?

Today with time the lag on real time data just is playing catchup when intermediate data may not have value.

#### Debouncing does not work for this usecase

In the application I have the UI refresh of < 100ms is a requirement. so I can't just set a delay for all of the changes to come in. I want to start rerendering as soon as I get input but want to prevent one of the setState calls if the rerender is not complete and 2 new values have arrived.

Comment: You can throttle the function that calls `setState`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React use debounce with setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60789246/react-use-debounce-with-setstate)