# Throttle touch event with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, throttling

I have a div and when I drag my finger up I want a number inside the div to increase.

When I drag my finger down I want the number inside to decrease.

This is fairly simple to implement with a touch event.

The codesandbox is here - I tried to make it as simple as possible! [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-flower-pk0r8)

Where I have a problem is the event fires really quickly, and this makes it difficult to land on a particular number. It would be great to throttle the event using a lodash throttle function, but here I get into problems! Nothing happens!

I tried using useRef like so:

```
const throttledPosition = useRef(throttle(touchPosition => touchPosition, 200)).current;
```

Again, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Part 1 - Throttling Event Handler

Your first issue is caused by the way you are using `_.throttle()`, it should ideally be wrapped around your event handler callback.

Please review the examples in [`lodash.throttle() docs`](https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle) for reference on usage.

Also have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54666401/how-to-use-throttle-or-debounce-with-react-hook) it may offer you some more insight into using throttle within React Hooks.

The key change was to wrap the event callback with `throttle`.

```
  const throttledSetPosition = throttle(event => {
    if (event.touches[0].clientY) {
      if (slider.current.contains(event.target)) {
        setTouchPosition(Math.round(event.touches[0].clientY));
      }
    } else {
      setTouchPosition(null);
    }
  }, 200);

  const handleTouchMove = useCallback(throttledSetPosition, [touchPosition]);
```

### Part 2 - Increasing/Decreasing Value

To achieve your goal of increasing/decreasing the displayed value, you first need to identify a scale. What is the max-min you want displayed? Let's use `100` as that is easily understood.

What you then need to calculate is the percentage of `100` the user is currently touching at, but reversed (since closer to the top is really closer to `100` and further down is closer to `0`).

To do this you could use the following:

```
// Define the scale
const scale = 100;

// Extract needed variables from event touches array
const {
  clientY,
  target: { offsetHeight, offsetTop }
} = event.touches[0];

// Calculate the percentage
const percentage = (clientY - offsetTop) / offsetHeight;

// Make the calculation to be reversed by subtracting the percentage from the scale...
const currentValue = scale - (percentage * scale);

// Set the display value
setTouchPosition(Math.round(currentValue));
```

I have forked your [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-mirzakhani-hlid3) with the above alterations.

Comment: Thanks for giving it some thought! I tried playing around with the delay and it doesn't seem to delay between each callback?

Comment: I just updated my answer and sandbox with an altered version following the answers given in the SO question I also recently added. Sorry for the many edits! let me know if it still isn't behaving as expected.

Comment: Ok this is behaving a lot better, but the thing that confuses me is that, if I want the number to increment by 1 if event.touches[0].clientY is +ve and I change setTouchPosition(Math.round(event.touches[0].clientY)); to setTouchPosition(touchPosition + 1); - it doesn't work anymore

Comment: updated my answer and sandbox to calculate the displayed value based on a "scale", in the example I use 100, but you can use whatever scale you want, it should work the same.