# Clean way to use React hook state in a debounced callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
function Foo() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  const cb = useCallback(debounce(() => {
    console.log(state);
  }, 1000), []);
  return ...;
}
```

In this example, `state` can become stale in the callback. One way I can think of to fix this is something like:

```
function Foo() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  const cbHelper = useCallback(debounce((state2) => {
    console.log(state2);
  }, 1000), [])
  const cb = () => cbHelper(state);
  return ...;
}
```

However, this looks pretty messy. Is there a cleaner/better way to do this?

Edit:

I can't just do the following because `debounce` won't work:

```
useCallback(debounce(() => {
  console.log(state);
}, 1000), [state]);
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to recommend a different approach without more explanation of your problem. One approach that might be considered to avoid stale variables in the callback closure is by using `useRef` and keeping your state encapsulated in the ref. The ref object will only be created once, so the callback closure will have access to the same ref as the component.

Comment: The use-debounce solution suggested by Fadi Quader seems to work in this way (using useRef to encapsulate the state).

Comment: I recently implemented `useDebounce` and `useThrottle` with lodash helpers. If you are interested: the answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62017005/5669456).

Answer (score 1):

I've used [use-debounce](https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce) to manage that

```
import { useDebouncedCallback } from 'use-debounce';

function Input({ defaultValue }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);
  // Debounce callback
  const [debouncedCallback] = useDebouncedCallback(
    // function
    (value) => {
      setValue(value);
    },
    // delay in ms
    1000
  );

  // you should use `e => debouncedCallback(e.target.value)` as react works with synthetic evens
  return (
    <div>
      <input defaultValue={defaultValue} onChange={(e) => debouncedCallback(e.target.value)} />
      <p>Debounced value: {value}</p>
    </div>
  );
```

}