# Why when I change slider value it sends a lot of ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, lodash

I have such function (I'm using `debounce` from `lodash`):

```
    const sliderDebounce = debounce(() => {
        postSliderVal({ email_instances }) //POST 
    }, 1000);
```

I guess it should send 1 request after 1 second but it send a lot of requests, how I can send 1 request when I will change the slider value?

Comment: You are debouncing your arrow function, not the `postSliderVal()` function. Remove the arrow function wrapper.

Comment: @RandyCasburn in this case i have such problem  Uncaught TypeError: Expected a function

Comment: You defined it just fine - https://jsbin.com/munanaz/edit?html,js,console,output. The issue is probably because that you use hooks. A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54666401/863110) (it's about `throttle` but it applies `debounce` too)